# Calculate remaining time intervals(begin date -> end date) after substracting other time intervals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, time, intervals

The following script calculates the remaining time intervals after substracting other specific time intervals.

In the end I am left with the interval filled with gaps.

Here is the script I created. Does anyone know a better way to do this ?

```
        SELECT * FROM SuspensionPeriod susPer WHERE id_document = 564148

DECLARE @idDocument BIGINT, @docBeginDate DATETIME, @docEndDate DATETIME

SET @idDocument = 564148

SELECT @docBeginDate = start_date, @docEndDate = end_date FROM Document md WHERE md.id_document = @idDocument

SELECT RowNum = Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY suspended_from), *
INTO   #SuspensionPeriods
FROM   SuspensionPeriod susPer WHERE susPer.id_document = @idDocument

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT

SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT Max(RowNum) FROM   #SuspensionPeriods)

DECLARE @Iter INT

SET @Iter = (SELECT Min(RowNum) FROM   #SuspensionPeriods)

DECLARE @intervalBegin DATETIME, @intervalEnd DATETIME

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
  BEGIN

      IF @Iter = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @intervalBegin = @docBeginDate
            SELECT @intervalEnd = suspended_from FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter

            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print '============================='


            --SELECT @intervalBegin = suspended_until FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter
            --SELECT @intervalEnd = suspended_from FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter + 1

            --print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            --print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            --print '============================='
        END

      IF @Iter <> 1 AND @Iter <> @MaxRownum
        BEGIN
            SELECT @intervalBegin = suspended_until FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter - 1
            SELECT @intervalEnd = suspended_from FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter 

            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print '============================='


            SELECT @intervalBegin = suspended_until FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter
            SELECT @intervalEnd = suspended_from FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter + 1

            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print '============================='
        END

      IF @Iter = @MaxRownum
        BEGIN
            --SELECT @intervalBegin = suspended_until FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter - 1
            --SELECT @intervalEnd = suspended_from FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter

            --print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            --print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            --print '============================='

            SELECT @intervalBegin = suspended_until FROM   #SuspensionPeriods WHERE  RowNum = @Iter
            SELECT @intervalEnd = @docEndDate 

            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalBegin,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print dbo.fnFormatDate(@intervalEnd,'yyyy.MM.dd')
            print '============================='
        END
      -- run your operation here
      SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
  END

DROP TABLE #SuspensionPeriods
```

Comment: What does "better" mean? What is the problem with the script you already have? If it's giving incorrect results then you need to show some sample data and reduce the script to the minimum required to show the problem, e.g. the PRINTs and comments above are not relevant.

Comment: Short answer = yes.  Very linear in it's programming (adding a row number so it can be done as an incremented while loop is poor sql logic, you want to do all rows at once) and could probably be switched into something set-based, possibly one statement.  You'll need to give us some table schema and a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish, there isn't enough info here to write you an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT MIN(md.start_date), MIN(sp.suspended_from)
    FROM Document md
    JOIN SuspensionPeriod sp ON sp.id_document = md.id_document
    WHERE md.id_document = @idDocument
UNION
SELECT sp.suspended_to, (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(spnext.suspended_from), md.end_date) FROM SuspensionPeriod spnext WHERE sp.id_document=spnext.id_document AND spnext.suspended_from > sp.suspended_to)
    FROM Document md
    JOIN SuspensionPeriod sp ON sp.id_document = md.id_document
    WHERE md.id_document = @idDocument
```